# How to have 2 WizardImageFiles,if it is possible

Tags: inno-setup

So,i would like to put two different WizardImageFiles to my setup.One WizardImageFile on welcome page,and other one on finished page,is it possible? I am using Inno setup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is possible. You can e.g. let the installer use the [`WizardImageFile`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_wizardimagefile) directive for the image on the welcome page, and load a different one to the final page `WizardBitmapImage2` image with a script like this:

```
[Setup]
AppName=My Program
AppVersion=1.5
DefaultDirName={pf}\My Program
WizardImageFile=WelcomeImage.bmp

[Files]
Source: "FinalImage.bmp"; Flags: dontcopy

[Code]
procedure InitializeWizard;
begin
  // extract the file from the [Files] section to the temporary folder
  ExtractTemporaryFile('FinalImage.bmp');
  // and load the just extracted bitmap to the image on the final page
  WizardForm.WizardBitmapImage2.Bitmap.LoadFromFile(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\FinalImage.bmp'));
end;
```